# Calling parent function in controller from grandchild directive results in undefined parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm relatively new to Angular and am likely approaching this incorrectly.  I am displaying a menu list and have packaged this functionality into two directives:

- **MenuItemRepeater** takes a list of items and displays them
- **AddMenuItem** allows for the addition of a new item to the list, called from the MenuItemRepeater

I have isolated scope in these directives and am calling a function in the parent controller once the user enters and submits text for a new menu item. The parent function is called correctly but the argument that I pass comes across as undefined.  Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <menu-item-repeater list="list" courseText="nameOfCourse" add-item-func="addMenuItemFun()"></menu-item-repeater>
</div>
```

and my controller/directive logic:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myController", function($scope){
    $scope.list = [];
    var item1 = {name:'Item 1',course:'test1'};
    var item2 = {name:'Item 2',course:'test2'};
    $scope.list.push(item1);
    $scope.list.push(item2);
    $scope.addMenuItemFun = function (item) {
       try {
         var itemToAdd = {
            name: item.name,
            course: item.course
         };
         $scope.list.push(itemToAdd);
       }
       catch(err) {
          alert(err);
       }
   };
});

myApp.directive('menuItemRepeater', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',        
        template: '<div ng-repeat="item in list">{{item.name}}</div><add-menu-item courseText="courseText" add-item="addItemFunc()"></add-menu-item>',
        scope: {
            courseText: '@coursetext',
            addItemFunc: '&',
        }
    }
});
myApp.directive('addMenuItem', function(){
    return {
        retstrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="form-group"><label for="name">Name of new item: </label><input ng-model="itemName" type="text" class="form-control" id="itemName" ><input ng-model="courseText" type="hidden" value="{{courseText}}" />            </div>                                 <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addNewItem1()">Submit</button>',        
        scope: {            
            courseText: '@couresetext',
            addItem: '&',
            itemName: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, $element) {                        
            scope.addNewItem1 = function () {                
                var newItem = {
                    name: scope.name,                                                                                
                    course: scope.courseText
                };
                scope.addItem({ item: newItem });
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Here's a Plnkr showing the issue.  Am I approaching this the wrong way?  What would the preferred pattern be for this?

http://plnkr.co/edit/fksSl5yeEFLtMsf4poKv

Comment: you didn't pass anything `add-item-func="addMenuItemFun()"`

Comment: Not sure I understand. What would I pass in this case as the parameter is entered via the input in the add-menu-item directive?  Can you modify the plunker?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues going on here but the main one is that with `&` you are binding to an *expression* which means that you will end up calling the controller's function as-is, i.e. `addMenuItemFun()` with no arguments -- thus you'll never get an item.

You need to write this as `addMenuItemFun(item)` (or whatever you want to name the argument).

This returns an expression that you can evaluate in the directive. Angular allows you to access arguments by name in the expression.

```
add-item="addItemFunc({nameOfItemArgument: item})"
```

You are also not passing in `courseText` correctly at times. It's best not to mess around with capitalization in the templates themselves.

Working version: http://plnkr.co/edit/a9T7pbmD2nW0QqBXxxb2?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for this but it looks like you worked off of the original plunker I posted which was not entirely correct.  The menu-repeater has the ng-repeat within it.  I'm passing a list of items to it so I wouldn't be able to pass an individual item as a parameter.  See the updated link that shows what I'm referring to: http://plnkr.co/edit/fksSl5yeEFLtMsf4poKv